# Не могу реализовать триггер с запросами в разные БД с вложенными запросами

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, phpmyadmin

Доброго времени суток

Есть таблица oc_product, в которой есть столбцы

`product_id`,

`quantity`,

`price`.

Есть таблица зависимостей map_product: там указывается сколько в каком товаре других товаров, т.е. столбцы

`flower` - id составного товара в таблице oc_product,

`bunch` - id товара в таблице oc_product, который входит в этот составной,

`count` - количество вхожения bunch в flower.

Таблицы, ввиду устройства, находятся в разных БД

Попытался на скорую руку скрафтить триггер, который будет изменять цену на составной товар при изменении цены входящего в составной товар.

На примере это составной букет из 3-х красных роз, 5-ти белых, 7-ми синих.

Мы изменили цену на синюю розу, нужно пересчитать цену на составной букет.

Вот код того убожества, которое я выдумал:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER price_change 
 after 
update ON `cms_flower`.oc_product  
BEGIN 
UPDATE `oc_product` SET `price` = 
(SELECT SUM(`summa`) FROM (SELECT `bunch` * `count` * 
(SELECT `price` FROM `oc_produc` 
WHERE `product_id` = 
(SELECT `bunch` FROM `flower_deliver`.map_product 
WHERE `flower` = NEW.product_id)) 
AS `summa` 
FROM `flower_deliver`.map_product 
WHERE `flower` = NEW.product_id)) 
WHERE `product_id` = (SELECT `bunch` FROM `flower_deliver`.map_product 
WHERE `flower` = NEW.product_id)
 END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Выдаёт:

> check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for
>   the right syntax to use near 'BEGIN  UPDATE `oc_product` SET `price` =
>   (SELECT SUM(`summa`) FROM (SELECT `bun' at line 4

Не знаю как реализовать такой триггер ввиду моей неопытности, прошу помогите, заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Идея триггера на событие обновления таблицы, которое выполняет обновление записи этой же таблицы - сама по себе порочна. Не говоря уж о том, что имеется потенция получить цикл, наглухо повесив сервер, причём подсистема целостности такую зависимость не отловит. Настоятельно рекомендую от триггера отказаться.

А двойного вхождения не бывает (цветок является частью букета, который является частью корзины)? если да - совсем дело плохо...

Полагаю, гораздо более правильным решением будет реализация логики обновления не триггером, а в формате хранимой процедуры. Там и рекурсию можно организовать, и многоуровневость, и учесть, что обновляемый товар может входить в несколько составных, и упростить себе жизнь временными таблицами.

Comment: Конечно здорово, но как реализовать тело этой процедуры?
Хоть в какую сторону копать, слишком много подзапросов, даже если их загнать в view

Answer (score 1):

Вот неоптимальный, но зато понятный алгоритм.

В процедуру передаём ID (или что-то ещё идентифицирующее) изменяемого товара и новую цену. Положим эти сведения во временную таблицу с уникальным индексом по товару (достаточно полей ID и стоимость). Получим запросом все товары, которые зависят от товаров во временной таблице, положим их во вторую временную таблицу (той же структуры и тоже индексированную по товару) запросом INSERT IGNORE. Вторым запросом получим стоимости товаров из второй временной таблицы, и положим их в первую запросом INSERT IGNORE. Если при этом AFFECTED ROWS не нулевой - повторим процедуру. Если же нулевой - выполним REPLACE основной таблицы данными из первой временной. Всё.

Сложность может вызвать разве что второй запрос - в нём надо будет для получения цены использовать как основную, так и первую временную таблицы. То есть ко второй временной привязать их обе по ID (temp2 INNER JOIN main LEFT JOIN temp1) и получать цену как COALESCE(temp1.price, main.price).

Comment: нууу, насчёт понятный...

Comment: тут не завязано количество count товаров в составном

Comment: А количество нужно исключительно при расчёте новой цены.

Comment: шеф, ничего не ясно

Comment: никак не могу прикинуть как написать